# How do I can still select data and have another data from column that have updated to value date (deleted) from other table? (Sql Eloquent Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, debugging, eloquent, export-to-excel

At first, I took data from the main table (Student) then if there is no data number in the phone table then it is left blank so I use left join if there is empty data.

Each student can have one or more telephone numbers or none.
the goal in this is to export an excel file using Laravel 8

i use whereNull('phone.deleted_at') condition to not display deleted data in phone table

**My Code Here**

```
$data = Student::select([student.name, student.email, phone.number as phone_number])
       ->leftJoin('phone', 'student.id', '=', 'phone.student_id')
       ->whereNull('phone.deleted_at')
       ->groupBy('student.id', 'phone.deleted_at', 'student.name', 'student.email')
       ->get();
```

**First Case Result**

| Name | Email | Phone Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Erwin | erwin@com | 081234567 |
| Joni | jon@com |  |
| Desy | desy@com | 083774512 |

At the beginning of the table that has been exported the results are in accordance with what I asked for. but if in one of Erwin's examples, there is an update on his phone number in the table that the deleted_at column changes to a date value (meaning it has been deleted)

so the student select table doesn't want to show Erwin's data because there was an update on his phone number that changed to a date value (deleted).

**Result I don't want**

| Name | Email | Phone Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joni | jon@com |  |
| Desy | desy@com | 083774512 |

I want the data to be deleted but it can still display Erwin's data, only the phone number data is blank because it has been deleted.

**Result I want**

| Name | Email | Phone Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Erwin | erwin@com |  |
| Joni | jon@com |  |
| Desy | desy@com | 083774512 |

can anyone have me to fix this? :( 
(can modified the code above)

Comment: You have to use laravel relation for this like One to many relation. follow this link. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: you are missing `'` in your `whereNull`

Comment: @SuperDj thanks for the notification, its just typo

Comment: @IrshadKhan already set to haveMany relation

Answer (score 0):

If you have added `use SoftDeletes;` trait to your `PhoneNumber` model, there is no need to add `whereNull` inside query.
In this case next query will get all students and non deleted phone numbers from database. This implies you correctly added your relationships to Eloquent model classes (Student and PhoneNumber)

```
$students = Student::with('phoneNumber')->get();
```

If you want to modify query for your relationship just add second argument to `with()` function as in following example:

```
$students = Student::with('phoneNumber', function($q) {
    $q->where('yourPhoneNumberQueryCondition');
})->get();
```

Comment: i using
->with('phoneNumber', function($q){
        $q->whereNull('phone.deleted_at');
})
but it shows all the data include deleted_at (not null), its there any conditions that can be affected?

Comment: Why not use softdelete trait? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: already include in the model Student and Phone, also i add the relation too hasMany() in StudentModel with belongTo in PhoneModel.

Comment: If you added SoftDelete trait in your model, you don't need to query `whereNull('deleted_at)` since it's already automatically included via trait. You can install Laravel Debugbar (or any other tool) - you can inspect your actual generated SQL queries with this tools.

Comment: Also I noticed your tables are in singular naming convention, which is a bad practice. Your tables names should be `students` and `phones`.  If you want to use `student` (singular) you will have to override table name in your Student model -> `protected $table = 'student';`